# Countifs with one range is a table and the other range a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to do a countifs where one range is a table (A2:B5 the table "color") and the other range is a column (C2:C5 the table "animals")

Here is the formula:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$B$5,"red",C2:C5,"fish")
```

**I want to count all the red in the table color but only want them to be counted  if on the same row the column animals shows fish.**

The formula return an error `#Value!`
What is the appropriate way to do this please?

Comment: Are you looking for "red" in __either__ `A:A` or `B:B` or in __both__ `A:A` and `B:B`?

Comment: To add to @Glitch_Doctor 's question, if it can be in either. Should "red" in `A:A` and `B:B` in the same row count as 1 occurance or as 2?

Comment: Also to answer your question indirectly, you're getting a `#VALUE!` error, because `=COUNTIFS()` can't compare two differently sized ranges (eg. in your case `A2:B5` contains 8 cells, meanwhile `C2:C5` contains only 4, resulting in the error.  I can't however give you a direct answer, if you don't add proper detail to your question as to what exactly you're trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

If you provide sample input and output, it'll be easier to understand. Maybe is this what you're looking for?

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A5, "red", $C2:$C5, "fish")
+COUNTIFS(B2:B5, "red", $C2:$C5, "fish")
```